# Recognition and recording of digits from external window in real time using python

Tags: python

I want to gather numbers that are being output from a specific window in real time as data points.

I have a piece of equipment with an internal pressure level I would like to monitor. The only output that the software I'm using gives me is a single float from the last ~second in a box within the software. I've asked the manufacturers if there was any way of internal accessing this output and they basically told me there is none.

Individual measurements don't mean much to me, and I'd like to see the change in pressure across time. But watching this single value all day isn't very practical for me. So I want to make something that can read a specific line of text by recognizing the words or by giving exact coordinates on the screen (either works), say 'Output PSI: ##.###' and get the ##.### in python as a data point every time the number changes.

Are there modules that anyone has experience with that might be of use here?

Comment: You'd have to analyze the screen itself and run a character recognition library to recognize the values. You can try with opencv and/or scikits-learn, but that's not a simple task...

Comment: Would it have to be the entire screen?

Comment: It depends on the tool used to record the screen and how you use it. Sorry I can't tell you more...